Is erc 20 smart contract real or fake
I was invested in erc20 but one day suddenly i m in contract ,now they demands remained money .can i send the money in contract or not .i think it is scam .help me guys what can i do now

Really hard to say from this description, but don't send anything anywhere before you're sure.
